# How to compute the fundamental group of a necklace of $\mathbb{S}^1$' s?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I was trying to compute $\pi_1 (X)$ where $X =$ "necklace of $n$ $\mathbb{S}^1$'s". At first, I tried using Van Kampen theorem however I could not find open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U \cap V$ is path connected. I tried using the covering space $E =\bigvee^\omega \mathbb{S}^1$ via the projection  as in the case of the real line covering the circumference, however I do not know how to compute $p_*( \pi_1 (E, e))$. I would appreciate an answer where one computes it using both methods (Van Kampen, maybe with an arbitrary colimit, and covering spaces).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the op means by $X$, that the right side of the first circle is glued at a point to the left side of the second circle, and the right of the second to the left of the third and so on to $n$, and then finally the right of the $n$th is glued to the left of the first.

First, stretch out the point at which the first and $n$th circles are glued together to be an interval with ends on either circle. Next, if we shrink the southern semicircles of each circle to a point, we see that this drags the ends of the stretched interval to the wedge point of $n$ circles and so adds another wedged circle. This operation is a homotopy equivalence and so $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{i=1}^{n+1} S^1$ and so $$\pi_1(X)\cong\pi_1(\bigvee_{i=1}^{n+1} S^1)\cong \ast_{i=1}^{n+1} \pi_1(S^1)\cong\ast_{i=1}^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}$$ ie the $(n+1)$-fold free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

Comment: I mean circles attached along another circle with this last circle erased. And, sorry,  it's not clear for me.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by 'last circle erased' ?

Comment: it's $\bigvee^n \mathbb{S}^1$ quotient the relation that associate a point from the first circle to a point from the last circle.

Comment: @DanielRust I believe the OP means 'circle 1 is attached to circle 2, which is attached to circle 3, which ... which is attached to circle $n$, which is attached to circle 1.'

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes

Comment: Ah, in that case it's $n$ circles instead of $n+1$. Just shrink the southern semi-circle of each circle to a point.

Comment: the problem in shrinking the southern semi circle is that the intersection of the open sets will not be path connected, indeed, even not connected.

Comment: @user40276 I don't understand. You can shrink the southern semicircles continuously in time until you are left with an $n$-fold wedge sum of circles - that is, these spaces are homotopy equivalent and so have isomorphic fundamental groups. The fundamental group of an $n$-fold wedge sum (of locally contractible spaces) is the $n$-fold free product of the fundamental groups of the individual spaces.

Comment: Oh, now I understood. However shrinking the southern semicircles is not an homotopy, otherwise you could shrink a circle to a point.

Comment: Each semicircle has a contractible neighbourhood so this is indeed a homotopy.

Comment: But, if i understood, the inner semicircles are homeomorphisc to a circle, hence it's not contractible.

Comment: By semi-circle, I specifically mean the following subset of $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid\|z\|=1\}$. The southern semi-circle of $S^1$ is the set $A=\{z\in S^1\mid Im(z)\leq 0\}$ This subspace is clearly homeomorphic to a closed interval.

Comment: Sorry, but if I understood you mean a star-shaped boundary and, then, it's not contractible. Of course, you can shrink it in $\mathbb{C}$, but not in the space itself.

Comment: Sorry I missed where you said the last and first circles were also glued together at a point. This adds one more circle to the wedge.

Comment: @user40276 I'm quoting the following theorem from memory so their may be more conditions that I'm forgetting, but it is applicable to this problem. If $X$ is a topological spaces and $A$ is a closed, contractible subspace of $X$, then the space $X/A$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$

Comment: @DanielRust I think you need $X$ and $A$ to be CW complexes, but they are in this case.

Comment: @JamesCameron That seems reasonable. I think maybe it applies to all locally contractible spaces as well.

Comment: Sorry, but how can you drag the ends of the unit interval to a unique point?

Comment: @user40276 Perhaps it's easier to consider the case $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an interval glued at two distinct points. Can you see how we can shrink the path (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) between the two end points of the interval, which acts as a 'dragging' motion on the end points, leaving us with a space that looks like $\mathbb{R}^2\vee S^1$. The same thing is happening here, except we're shrinking a contractible subspace of $X$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: "contractible subspace of X"?

Comment: A subspace of $X$ which is contractible (as a topological space on its own)

Comment: sorry, but what subspace?

Comment: I'm referring the to union of the southern semi-circles in your space $X$, after stretching one of the glue-points to an interval.

Comment: Yes, however how can you drag the endpoint to the other endpoint? you will have to drag along all the southern circles.

Comment: Maybe dragging isn't the right word (sorry, you tend to use this loose language after working with these spaces for a while). Formally, if $A$ is the above mentioned subspace of $X'$ (Where $X'$ is $X$ with a point stretched to an interval), then $A$ is a contractible subspace of $X'$, and $X'/A$ is homotopy equivalent to $X'$. If $a$ and $b$ are the respective end points of the stretched interval, then the quotient map $q\colon X'\to X'/A$ has $q(a)=q(b)=q(A)$. That is, the end points of the interval are identified and at the wedge point of the other circles.

Comment: OK, thanks for the patience, now I understood the idea, but $X'/A$ being homotopy equivalent to $X'$ seems difficult to prove.

Comment: Using the theorem I quoted it's trivial. Proving that theorem is a bit more involved though, yes. My advice is to draw many **many** pictures and try to get an intuition for what kinds of operations can be considered homotopy equivalences and which can't.

Comment: I've just found that for the quoted theorem holds $A$ must have the homotopy extension property and, in this case, it's not true.

Comment: "If $X$ is a cell complex and $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$, then the pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property." This applies to the above example and so we do in fact have the homotopy extension property.

Comment: Hello. How could I calculate the fundamental group of a necklace of toruses? Is there a way to generalise the reasoning made for the circles?

Comment: Sure, just stretch one of the 'tubes' and then slide the end of the tube from one end of the chain of tori to the other. This creates one extra tori at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The space you are talking about is a finite graph, namely a graph with $n$ vertices, and two edges joining vertices $i$ and $i+1 \pmod{n}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. To find the fundamental group of a graph, you take any spanning tree and contract it to a point (this doesn't change the homotopy tpye as the tree is contractible); what you get is a bouquet of some number $k$ of circles, and thus the fundamental group is the free group on $k$ generators. For your graph, the path of length $n-1$ that goes $1\to2\to \cdots \to n$ is a spanning tree. There are $(n-1) + 2 = n+1$ edges that are *not* part of the tree, so the fundamental group is free on $n+1$ letters.

Comment: Nice, but I don't know fundamental groups of graphs. Do you have any reference (I just know Serre's book but it's kinda advanced)?

Comment: Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, [section 1.A, page 83](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf).